# Revel cli won't create a new project

Tags: windows, go, frameworks, command-line-interface, revel

I am trying to start a new project with the revel's CLI `revel new revelApp1` and its giving me some errors:

```
C:\Users\myUserame\go\src>revel new revelApp1
Revel executing: create a skeleton Revel application
Error stack [utils.go:109 command_config.go:232 new.go:187 new.go:126 revel.go:109 proc.go:203 asm_amd64.s:1357]
ERROR 20:04:52    new.go:187: Failed to import package                  error="exit status 1" gopath=C:\\Users\\myUserame\\go GO-ROOT=C:\\Go output="#
 cd C:\\Users\\myUserame\\go\\src\\github.com\\mattn\\go-isatty; git pull --ff-only\nFrom https://github.com/mattn/go-isatty\n   0e9ddb7..cb30d62  mas
ter     -> origin/master\n * [new tag]         v0.0.11    -> v0.0.11\n * [new tag]         v0.0.12    -> v0.0.12\nerror: Your local changes to the
following files would be overwritten by merge:\n\tgo.mod\nPlease commit your changes or stash them before you merge.\nAborting\npackage github.com/
mattn/go-isatty: exit status 1\n"
ERROR 20:04:52   proc.go:203: Unable to execute                         error="Failed to fetch revel github.com/revel/revel[error exit status 1]"
```

```
GOHOSTOS=windows
GOPATH=C:\Users\myUserame\go
GOBIN=C:\Go\bin
```

Comment: Looks like you have made some local changes to C:\\Users\\myUserame\\go\\src\\github.com\\mattn\\go-isatty\\go.mod. Revert that and retry.

Comment: i manually download a zip from that package and just pased it and commited and it worked!!! wierd cuz i just download that cli  anyway thanks burak-serdar